# Understanding physics principals behind machining

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am a mechanical engineering student and I want to design a desktop machining lathe for light polymers and soft metals. I am in my second year of course work, so I am unsure of how to go about obtaining and calculating information about the physics behind drilling/milling and how it relates to material properties, torque, and power.

Anyone have any good resources or governing equations to go into deeper research on the subject? I have taken my mechanics of materials and material science course, so I understand linear deformations and basic material properties.

My biggest problem is definitely understanding whether or not the motor I choose will be enough to cut through the material and how quickly.

Comment: I recommend finding a book on machining & machine shop equipment design from like 1920.

Comment: Small motors make small cuts….

Comment: Do a search for watchmakers lathes.

Comment: You don't need to know the physics of the cutting tools to make the lathe since you are just going to be buying and using the cutting tools, not designing them for the most part. There's too much diversity anyways between combinations of material, operation, and tooling and each one is a rabbit hole. And much of it is not in equations (certainly not ones you want to do by hand), and not necessarily even computer models, but in empirical testing and tables. They are not simple and you do not need to go into that complexity anyways.

Comment: You should just look at pre-existing examples for their motor power and the speeds they have available and go with that. You will *always* be wanting for power and rigidity in a desk machine so go as much as you can for your form factor. Have you used a lathe before? From what you're asking for in your question I'm guessing you haven't. You shouldn't try and build one without at least dabbling on one for a while first with a few basic operations on different materials with different tooling.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MlOSYf7knpg

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what @DKNguyen commented is still how the field mostly look like. We lack computer models for most machining tools we use.

Unlike EE heavily built on electromagnetic axioms, machining is a practice that developed since before Issac Newton invented axiomatic mechanics. Much knowledge is empirical, verbally and visually transferred between professionals, and remains to be translated into computer models.

However, this should not stop us from developing and refining our own models. Just like electronic models abstracting on higher or lower levels from ESL to RTL and SPICE, machining models could be after different abstraction levels: geometric, mechanical, thermal, chemical etc. You often don't need the lower layers.

It's a good idea to begin from the **geometric level**:  what shape become what another shape after a specific machining process.

In a verbal example, any geometric object become the object minus a cylindrical void centered at (x,y) with diameter d after drilling (x,y) with a drill bit of diameter d.

In order for a computer to understand, we need a formal representation of geometric objects. The most popular format in the industry is AutoCAD (or Solidworks, UG, CATIA, I don't know), which might be too complicated for a simple reasoning system.

[OpenSCAD](https://openscad.org/) is a relatively new language that can describe complex shapes by composing relatively simple statements.

You might also want to read ["geometric-modeling" projects](https://github.com/topics/geometric-modeling) on github.

The geometric level does not address some realistic concerns, like what is the best feed rate and rotation rate for a given machining task, you would probably need a lower level model once you figure out the geometric level.

Comment: The models required to describe and simulate the live deformation of chips are relatively new and extremely computer intensive, they are  helpful for designing your tool geometry, but beyond complicated for what’s needed to design a nice machine.

Comment: @DrMrstheMonarch I agree with you, it's unnecessary to have a digital twin model of the lathe, but having it could make turning much easier and predictable for users of diverse backgrounds.

Comment: i suppose that‘s what cam simulations are for? Almost all CAM softwares simulate lathe and milling processes. InventerCAM / HSMworks is free for students even.

Comment: @DrMrstheMonarch it does not actually normally simulate cutting. But just the affects of the toolpath assuming the cut works as intended. Its not usually simulating motor stall conditions tool vibration etc. Just geometry moves thats ok its not really all one needs. Its also not true that there are calculations there are. Also even the chip formation calcs can be simplified to something more suitable. But you need empirical data tables.

Comment: @joojaa yes, but it’s entirely *not* required to simulate the cutting of metals like this. Read my answer.

Comment: Well no but you get a ballpark figure for spindle sizing quite easily. Is it needed, well not really you can just copy things. But its also not terribly hard math either. Advantage with calculation is that you can size bearings etc better but sure you dont actually need most engineering math if you just copy stuff.

Comment: @DrMrstheMonarch: formal or computational, I am curious how can we mathematically define a "lathe", and how can we mathematically define "what set of geometric shapes, up to what precision, can the lathe produce"?

Answer (score 1):

Your motivation is great. But you’re confusing the trees for the forest. An important part of engineering is understanding *when* you need to use complicated models or not. There is little point in trying to figure out if your hobby motor can handle what you want to do, when for 5$ more you just buy a bigger motor that has double the required power.

Lathes, milling machines and cnc machines are simple machines that have been in use for hundreds of years. Hobby machines at home you’d build for cutting plastics aren’t going to experience the kinda of loads, or dynamic vibrations your classes lead to you believe are important to know for the task at hand.

Look up ‘mini lathes’ like the emco unimat 3 and see what kind of motors and parts that machine has. Buy one even and take it apart. No-one in the 70s wrote down a single ode when designing that sweet little baby, (i own one of these laths exactly for what you want to do). They used classic design techniques that have been learned over the years, ones you’ll learn from your CAD classes.

Theory is fine and all, but you’ll learn far more taking things apart that already exist and then trying to improve them,  than trying to solve math.

Once you’ve taken something apart, learned the choices of others before you, then designed and built some machines (like a mini lathe, or 3d printer or something similar)
And they fail a couple times, you will have a far better understanding and more importantly a machine infront of you, rather than unsolvable complicated maths.

Look up hackaday.com and see all the things the people there have built without math and be inspired. Engineering is a fascinating field. But you gotta build. Don’t worry about failure. You will fail. But you’ll learn.

Good luck.